# Testing in flutter gives error MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to test the code for the login page in a flutter. This is the first time for me and I am just following the template provided by them. But whatever widget I try to push gives an error saying MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.

I have tried out by pumping different widgets in my app. But each and every widget gives the same error as mentioned above, on the other hand, my app is working fine on the device but while testing it gives the error for just pumping the widget.

```
await tester.pumpWidget(Login());
```

and Login page is simple Scaffold with appbar and body.

Comment: there should be a MaterialApp higher up in the hierarchy to access MediaQuery functions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this helper method :

```
 Widget buildTestableWidget(Widget widget) {
   return MediaQuery(data: MediaQueryData(), child: MaterialApp(home: widget));
 }
```

Then you can use inside your Test:

```
 await tester.pumpWidget(buildTestableWidget(Login()));
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough just to wrap "Widget under test" with MaterialApp? Something like this worked for my Widgets with Scaffold&AppBar:

`Widget makeTestableWidget(Widget child) {
    return MaterialApp(home: child);
}
`
What's the advantage of wrapping it with MediaQuery first ? I'm new to flutter as well so that's a genuine question as I don't understand this yet:)

Comment: I tested with both the diegoveloper and @Wazniak solutions and found no difference. The latter is simpler/cleaner, thus my preference. But, I am a noob. Are there situations where the former works and the latter does not?